# Automatic git push with tmux only working when attached to session

Tags: bash, github, directory, tmux

I have a script running in a tmux session, which automatically runs every 40 seconds, scans a directory for changes and pushes it to Github.

It works fine when I'm attached to the session. It scans, pushes and reruns the script. When I detach myself from the session (Ctrl b d) and log myself out, pushes come to hold. When I log back in (SSH) and attach again, I can read this:

> fatal: Could not change back to '(unreachable)/somedir/githubproject.io': No such file or directory

(unreachable) should be /home/username/

The moment I'm attached and the script cycle reloads, it pushes again. Thankful for any ideas. I'm on a VPS, KVM with encrypted harddrive. There is a teamspeak server running as well with no problems at all.

Comment: Sounds like some directory is unmounted when you log out.

Comment: @chepner That seemed to be the case. The problem fixed itself with an update this morning. Unfortunatly I could not find the borked lib. Thanks for answering though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fixed itself with an update this morning. Some lib seemed to be the problem, which I could not dertermine.